# Updating target href problem

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm working on a little image gallery, where you'd roll over a small thumbnail, the larger image would display over it. Clicking on the image would load a full size version in an overlay.

http://shopcoobie.server303.com/shop/

The issue is with the larger image, the rollovers are working fine, but the script I have updates the href which points to the full size image only seems to work the first time I click the image.

```
$$('.thumbs img').each(function(s) {

$(s).observe('mouseover', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var thumb = $(el).src;
    var large = $(el).alt;
    $(el).up(3).down(1).href = large;
    $(el).up(3).down(2).src = thumb;
    console.log((el).up(3).down(1).href);
    console.log(thumb);
 });
});
```

The console outputs the proper image reference, so it seems this should work (and partially does), Im just not sure why it only works once.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: goodness, you're using jquery, prototype and scriptapulous on the same site...are you sure you need all of them?

Comment: Prototype/Scriptaculous for my own JS, Foxycart uses JQuery which it loads itself. I keep thinking I should pick up a little JQuery, but I've grown used to many Prototype solutions like LightView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lightview plugin builds up its list of images first, then you change the src dynamically, and it doesn't update. So try adding a call to `Lightview.updateViews();` at the end of the mouseover handler above.

From [Lightview](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/):

> Lightview.updateViews(): Force a reset of all Lightview
>   elements on the page. Most of the time
>   you won't need to do this since
>   Lightview will pick up on newly
>   inserted elements automatically. After
>   updating existing elements it might be
>   required to call this function.

So yours is a case where it doesn't automatically pick up the change.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Thanks Dave!